# Can't clone repo using git clone git://... - ok with git clone http://

Tags: git, http, git-clone

Git newbie here. I'm setting up git on a new Ubuntu VM and trying to clone some repos. The clone works for the following command:

```
git clone http://github.com/organisation_name/repo_name
```

(after prompt for username/password), but fails for

```
git clone git://github.com/organisation_name/repo_name
```

and also

```
git clone git://github.com/organisation_name/repo_name.git
```

with the same error message:

```
Cloning into 'repo_name'...
fatal: remote error:
Repository not found
```

Of course the obvious answer is *"use the `http` method"*, but I'm trying to understand why one works and the other doesn't. Any suggestions? (also is there any difference when using the `.git` extension on the repo name btw?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I think you are using the wrong url in your second case

Try this instead

```
git clone git@github.com:organisation_name/repo_name.git
```

The difference is the `:` in the url when using `git@` vs the `/` you are currently using, and the extra `.git` at the end.

This should be the same url if you go to github and select the ssh url for cloning (and not the https one selected by default)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using the command you've supplied gives a slightly different error... > Cloning into '<repo_name>'...
> fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
> github.com: Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Comment: sorry - trouble with mini-Markdown, error added above. how do I do newlines?!

Comment: Aha - There is no ssh url for cloning, it says "HTTPS clone URL"

Comment: There should be a ssh url as well, its a small link just below the url

Comment: Sorry for confusion! Got it

Comment: Now tell me how to +1 your answer (stackoverflow newbie as well!)

Comment: Just click on the grey up arrow besides the answer for upvoting, and the tick next to it for accepting :)

Comment: One more question :)  the how-to at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository says to use "git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git". what's the difference between that and the "clone git@github.com/..." method?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for that. But if you go to the last para, it mentions a number of ways, and git@github.com is one of the syntaxes.

Answer (score 7):

If this is a private repository, you need to add your machine's ssh public key to you account under https://github.com/settings/ssh otherwise you will get the exact error you are listing here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'd already added the SSH keys using the method described at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. Is there any other way I can verify my ssh key is ok?

Comment: Run "ssh git@github.com" and see what it returns. If you have it setup correctly, it should return your username and if you don't, it should return a failure authentication message. There is a possibility that your network has ssh outbound connections closed as well so if you get no answer, that would be my first guess.

Comment: Ok! Did that, I enter my passphrase, and I get the "you've successfully authenticated" message, but just before that is "PTY allocationrequest failed on channel 0". Any need to worry about this?

Comment: That's normal. After looking at ansh0l's answer, he's probably correct (I didn't look at the url too closely).

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to throw out there that my problem was the network. All of my settings were good. I was told the network didn't filter or block ports or anything, but after trying everything I could think of and everything I could find online; I finally tethered my laptop to my mobile phone and everything started working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Query: why HTTPS URL works and SSH URL doesn't?
The *purpose* of SSH URLs is to provide access to a Git repository via SSH, a *secure* protocol. To use these URLs, you must generate an SSH keypair on your computer and add the public key to your GitHub account.