# git clone: what's the difference between url git@github.com/... and url git://github.com/

Tags: git, url, github, clone

I'm following the git basics guide at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository, and after having had my initial question answered at [Can't clone repo using git clone git://... - ok with git clone http://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683557/cant-clone-git-repo-using-git-clone-git-ok-with-git-clone-http) regarding how to use the git URL to clone a repo, I'm now wondering what the difference is between what the book says:

> git clone git://github.com/org_name/repo_name.git

and

> git clone git@github.com:org_name/repo_name.git

the latter works for me, the line from the book doesn't and gives me error message

> Cloning into 'repo_name'
>   fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   github.com: Servname is not supported for ai_socktype

While the obvious answer is "use the one that works", it'd be good to understand what the difference is and what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one uses the git protocol and the second one uses the ssh protocol. As github does not provide git protocol access you are getting an error.

Comment: Got it. So the ai_socktype error is caused by the lack of github support for git protocol access? You'd think they could have thought up a better error message :)

Comment: Well git can't possibly know who supports the git protocol so having a vague response is actually better in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

The first uses git's own protocol and works against a special git daemon. The latter accesses the repo over SSH. The protocols are explained in more detail [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html).

Comment: Thanks, the link looks really useful. I'd be interested to fix the "ai_socktype" error message though, and a quick google shows nothing much useful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The first one (`git://...`) specifies using the `git` protocol, but says nothing about the username to use. The second one `git@github.com:...` specifies the user `git`, but doesn't specify a protocol, and as a result will use `ssh` to connect.